# Java stream map call another constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to use java stream instead of forloop

```
ids.stream().map(AccountPermissionsUpdate::new)
```

I have created an other constructor,
my question is: how to call the second constructor

```
new AccountPermissionsUpdate(id,true)
```

Thanks

```
public AccountPermissionsUpdate(long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

public AccountPermissionsUpdate(long accountId, boolean forcedLogout) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.forcedLogout = forcedLogout;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note (learned from Josh Bloch's book Effective Java), stream api is not a replacement for for loops, so be careful as it creates many stream instances in between. You can read more about that in his book though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ids.stream().map(id -> new AccountPermissionsUpdate(id, true));
```

You will call it like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try out below code:

```
ids.stream().map(element -> new AccountPermissionsUpdate(element,true));
```

Comment: Wow you are fast, but the `id` seem not correct here, should be `element`?

Comment: Yes. My bad. It should be element. I will update my answer. I just copied and pasted your code from your question, that's didn't notice that.